# Нужно ли тире таки?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, обобщающее-слово

`Верно: «пришел», (—) потому что приставка -ПРИ- имеет значение приближения.`

Действует ли здесь [правило Розенталя — пункт 8 —](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103) о том, что запятая «поглощает» тире?

И можно ли слово *верно* назвать обобщающим?

Ваше мнение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Верно — «пришел**», потому что приставка ПРИ- имеет значение приближения.*

**Запятая** перед союзом  ПОТОМУ ЧТО обозначает **причинно-следственные** отношения.

Первая часть имеет **такой смысл**: графическая форма «пришел» является верной, в неполном варианте ставится **тире**, но **двоеточие** тоже возможно (при наличии **интонационного** предупреждения).

Сочетания знаков **там нет**

Comment: А если с двоеточием, тире нужно?

Comment: Верно; «пришел», потому что приставка ПРИ- имеет значение приближения.

Comment: В общем, поглощение, да?

Comment: А кого съели? Тире там изначально не было.

Comment: Почему же не было? Разве закрыть придаточную часть с двоеточием не надо? Или что это? Могу не все термины знать.

Comment: Мы по-разному понимаем структуру предложения. Блоки разные!  У меня граница идет перед подчин. союзом, а у вас после первого слова. Но и в вашем случае сочетания знаков нет.  "Верной будет такая запись:  пришел, потому что..."   Это бессоюзная связь, поясн. отношения.  Обозначаем двоеточием.

Answer (score 0):

Сэрчонок мой родненький, я считаю, что стоит — по контексту, в котором, я думаю, это используется, — немного предложение изменить, так как эта вторая часть, как видно, не является неотъемлемой.

> Верно: «пришел» (потому что приставка -ПРИ- имеет значение приближения).

> Верно: «пришел». (Приставка -ПРИ- имеет значение приближения.)

> Верно: «пришел». Приставка -ПРИ- имеет значение приближения.

Если причина суперочень важна, то паузы не будет, а следовательно:

> Верно «пришел» (писать), потому что приставка -ПРИ- имеет значение приближения.

Comment: Мне с двоеточием нужно и с причиной)

Comment: А трёх вариантов мало?

Comment: Вариант с тире или запятой — это здесь чушь.